# How to load Myanmar Language in Web View in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I have a web view in which i will enter the URL and load that content to that web view.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/urlField"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textUri"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:hint="http://proteam.in" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="open"
            android:text="@string/browse" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mayanmarbroswer;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText field;
    private WebView browser;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    final Context context = this;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override       
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.urlField);
        browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        //myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);

        WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webSettings.setFixedFontFamily("file:///android_asset/font/Sanpya.ttf");

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.hide();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        field.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) 
                {
                    if(field.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Valid WebSite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        open(v);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    public void open(View view){
        String url;
        if(field.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Valid WebSite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            if(field.getText().toString().startsWith("http://"))
            {
                url = field.getText().toString();
            }
            else
            {
                url = "http://" + field.getText().toString();
            }
            browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            browser.loadUrl(url);
        }
    }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
            // set indeterminate style
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            // set title and message
            //pDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Pls Wait");
            // and show it
            pDialog.show();*/
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //do what you want to do
            /*if (pDialog.isShowing())
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

URL 1: http://www.mora.gov.mm/
URL 2: http://www.saikwan.info/

i tested this in few android device like moto e (4.4.2), Dell venue 7 (4.4.2), Samsung Duos GT-s7392 (4.1.2) and Videocon  z40pro(4.2.2) the above given URL with myanmar font is working correctly. but when i try to load that in Samsung GT-s7582(4.2.2) the myanmar fonts are missing in web view. so, please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

### If you fetch data from resource folder i mean asset folder then try this way.

**Java Code**

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonPlayVideo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playvideoplayer);
    Button buttonPlayVideo1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button acceess = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

    //Displays a video file.   


   buttonPlayVideo1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // VideoView refference see main.xml
        VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

        //String uriPath = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.k;
        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.android.AndroidVideoPlayer/"+R.raw.demo;

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();


    }
});
```

### If you fetch from URL or FTP Server OR HTTP Connection then try this way

**Java Page**

```
    buttonPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             //VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

             Intent browserIntent = 
                     new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.8/aeon/"));  // For Video Content
                    // new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ftp://movies:movies@192.168.0.8/Transport_Streams/"));

            startActivity(browserIntent);




        }});

    acceess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidVideoPlayer.this,Videopage.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
 }
```

### XML Code Of Both Way are is Given Following way

**XML Page for when fetch from the resource**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF8800"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome To Aeon Group"
        android:textColor="#9933CC"
        android:textSize="3mm" />


        <VideoView
       android:id="@+id/videoview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="394dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/playvideoplayer"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Aeon Content" />

   <!--  <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />
 -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Play" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playvideoplayer"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Acces" />


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dilip: Thanks for your reply. I need a application which should fetch data from the URL like what i mentined above (URL 1: http://www.mora.gov.mm/ URL 2: http://www.saikwan.info/). it should be dynamic and request are handle in application itself, not any external application like (Chrome).

Comment: Yes i got  ur question so you can use second code that is intent

Comment: @user2969177 u want display whole page in android mobile of  http://mora.gov.mm and http://saikwan.info  of this URL  is this correct ?????

Comment: @Dhilip Intent browserIntent = 
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));  
           startActivity(browserIntent) but this code ask where to open in chrome or Firefox. i like to show that page in my web view itself.

Comment: @user2969177 **When u parse Any URL then it take automtic browser **